# Is there a way to make button group have like grid system property in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 in my app and using button group component in my app.
The button group has 6 button and i'm using btn-group-justified to make the width full. This is the code

```
<div class='btn-group btn-group-justified' role='group' aria-label='slot'>
  <div class='btn-group btn-group-xs' role='group'>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='1' name='menit'>00</button>
  </div>
  <div class='btn-group btn-group-xs' role='group'>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='2' name='menit'>10</button>
  </div>
  <div class='btn-group btn-group-xs' role='group'>";
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='3' name='menit'>20</button>
  </div>
...
```

here's the example image

[image]

What I want to achieve, is there a way to make the button group has a grid system like property using bootstrap alone ? Let say I want to delete number 10 button and make button 00 span wider to button 10 place. Its like using grid system in bootstrap.  The problem is button justified make all button has the same width. I'm open to CSS solution too.

Answer (score -1):

You can define the width as in following snippet. You will have to tweak the percentages to fit your specific needs.

```css
.btn-group-justified .btn.weight-1{
    width: 25%;
}

.btn-group-justified .btn.weight-2{
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary weight-2">Apple</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary weight-1">Samsung</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary weight-1">Sony</a>
</div>
```